# A probleme when trying to lauch the node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth, quorum

I am trying to build a quorum node from scratch and I have folowed this tutorial: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/From-Scratch

When i try to execute the node using this command:

```
   PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir new-node-1 -- 
   nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 
   50000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi 
   admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft 
   --emitcheckpoints --port 21000 2>>node.log &
```

I get this output

```
   [1] 32123
```

and when I try

```
    geth attach newnode/geth.ipc
```

I get

```
    no such file or directory
```

do you have any in formations what does thisoutput mean [1] 32123??

Answer (score 0):

The output `32123` is the process id of the geth process. This is normal Unix output, nothing to do with Quorum. To get more information on that I suggest you read some Unix documentation on how processes are run in the background using "&".

In your command line I can see that you are starting the geth process with the data directory `--datadir new-node-1`. However, you are trying to attach to the IPC file in the `newnode` directory.
I suggest you try:

```
geth attach new-node-1/geth.ipc
```

If you still can't connect then check that the ipc file exists. If it doesn't then it means that the geth process is failing to run. You can check this using 'ps' and look in the log file (node.log) for any errors.